# Этимология сезонов года

Tags: этимология

Вот сейчас подумалось. Каждый месяц славянского календаря в своем названии отражал какие-то его погодные и прочие свойства. Одновременно слова "весна", "лето", "осень" и "зима" не говорят современному человеку ни о чем. Какова их этимология?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ОСЕНЬ.** Древн. слав, слово. Имеет соответствия в других и.-е. языках. Соврем, его форма развилась из праслав. *jesenь «осень» вследствие утраты j и изменения в др.-рус. яз. нач. е перед последующим е в гласн. о (ср. ст.-сл. Ѥсень «осень», откуда 
фамилия Есенин; польск. jesien — «осень» и т. п.). В праслав.* jesenь звук j фонетически развился перед е в нач. слова. О первонач. знач. слова осень, вероятно, свидетельствует этимологически родств. готтское asans «время жатвы».

**ЛЕТО**. Праслав. Достоверной этимол. не имеет. Полагают, что это слово образовано по типу 
глаг. имен *жито, сито* от глаг. *лить* в его древн. форме *leiti «лить» и первонач. значило «время дождей». Лето как время дождей противопоставлялось зиме как времени 
снега. Другие сопоставляют слово лето с ирл. lith «праздник» и усматривают в нем первонач. знач. «праздник природы». Третьи считают, что слово лето происходит от выражения lěto (vermę) «прекрасное» (время). Ему соответствует лат. laetus «прекрасный». Знач. «год» у слова лето является вторичным.

**ЗИМА**. Древн. слав. слово. Имеет соответствия в других и.-е. языках. Праслав. *zima «зима» происходит от и.-е.* ĝheima «холодное неприятное время», в нем суф. -m-а и корень *ĝhei-. Ср. др.-инд. himas «холод»; греч. cheo «лью», «валю», cheima «зима, буря», 
chion «снег»; лат. hiems «дождливое время года», «ненастье». На слав. почве и.-е.* ĝh изменился в z, дифтонг ei — в гласн. i. Знач. могло развиваться так: «холодное, неприятное время» > «время осадков» > «время осадков в виде снега» > «время года, зима».

**ВЕСНА**. Праслав. Образовано, вероятно, с суф. -н-а со знач. состояния (как *тайна*) от и.-е. корня *vesсо знач. «светить». Ср. др.-инд. vesantas «весна», vasaras «день», собств. «ясный» (чередов. г//п). От сущ.* весна* образовано с суф. -ух-а (как пеструха) известное в диал. слово веснуха «веснушка», а от него с уменьш. суф. -ьк-а веснушка, мн. ч. веснушки «коричневые пятнышки па коже, особенно заметные весной».

Answer (score 1):

Осень - осенегь, о снеге, перед снегом.
Зима - зёма, позёма, позёмка, снег лёг на  землю.
Весна - вёсна, тает снег, сосульки висят.
Лето - лёто, птички летят.
Народ-то был простой, без знания авторов и всенародных потуг к поэтическим  образам. Главное свойство языка - понятность.

Comment: Не настолько же простой, чтобы в это поверить без надежных ссылок))))

Answer (score 1):

- **Осень** - из праиндоевропейского ***e̯eson*** - урожай, сбор урожая, осень.
- ***Зима*** - из праиндоевропейского ***ĝhi̯om*** - мороз, морозная погода
- ***Весна*** - из праиндоевропейского ***u̯esr*** - весна
- ***Лето*** - этимология неизвестна.

Answer (score 0):

По лету очень спорно всё. Время считают летами - это факт. Вопрос с каких годов.

Как по мне, массу слов в язык принесли аристократы 18-нач.19 века, которые говорили на французском (ок. 30%) и немецком (ок. 25%). Начиная от табурета и шкафа, заканчивая каникулами и шуточным Ку-ку.
Так вот по-французски лето - l'été.