# Времена года

Tags: семантика

Почему в русском языке (и родственных славянских) времена года называются именно так : зима, весна, лето, осень? 
Свою точку зрения представлю позже, с вашего позволения)
===
Спасибо, Валентин, за справку, прочитал со вниманием.
Лето - от слова "лить" (?)
Осень - "урожай" (?)
Зима - "время дождей" (?)
Весна - "светлая" (?)
Такие объяснения мне кажутся не совсем верными. Обсуждения, кстати, по ссылке нет никакого; участник olsa представила "академическое" словарное мнение и всё. Но ведь каждый может залезть в словарь и прочитать статью о любом слове, не так ли?
Фасмер, перечисляя версии своих собратьев по профессии, каждой даёт свою оценку : "не может быть", "маловероятно", "абсурд", "противоречие" и тд. Единого мнения нет в этимологии, ни по одному словечку...
Думать можно и нужно, уверяю вас)

Comment: Высказывайте тогда своё мнение. Посмотрим, окажется ли оно более правдоподобным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этимология времен года уже обсуждалась [**здесь**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), а *свои версии*, уверяю вас, здесь никто придумывать не станет.