# И еще о множественном числе - считаем годы

Tags: этимология

Пока писал предыдущий вопрос, появился следующий. 
Помню, в раннем детстве мне казалось, что пять лет - это определенная веха во взрослении, потому что тебе наконец-то становится не "года", а "лет".
И вот интересно, почему до пяти считаются годы ("Ему всего три годика"), а после пяти - лета ("Ей сорок лет")? В чем разница?
И еще, интересно, почему годы считают именно летами, а не зимами (которые в наших краях куда, скажем так, ярче лета) или другими временами года?

Answer (score 1):

> И вот интересно, почему до пяти считаются годы ("Ему всего три годика"), а после пяти - лета ("Ей сорок лет")? В чем разница?

Тут дело не в счете. "Лет" - это т.н. счетная форма для слова "год". Смотрите как устроенно согласование по числу с русскими числительными - один стол, два (три четыре) стола, пять (и более) - столов. Один - именительное единственное, Два - родительные единственного (на самом деле это рефлекс древнего двойственного числа, совпавший с родительным единственного), пять - родительный множественного. Вот это "множественное" и есть счетная форма. Т.е. на вопрос "в чем разница" я ответил.

> И еще, интересно, почему годы считают именно летами, а не зимами (которые в наших краях куда, скажем так, ярче лета) или другими временами года?

На самом деле все наоборот. "Лето" в древнерусском - это год. Исключительно временем года оно стало сравнительно недавно. Вообще, судя по всему, счет времени по сезонам не был слишком популярным у славян и на название сезона вполне могло распространиться слово, обозначающее год. Впрочем, слово "лето" в значении "время года" общеславянское, так что в глубокой древности вполне могло произойти обратное - название сезона стало названием года. Но это если и было, то так давно, то точно установить, как и почему, вряд ли получится.

Что касается названий сезонов вообще, то смотрите тут
[Этимология сезонов года](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)